# background image doesnt work external css

Tags: css, background-image

I was working on a project with the css in the head tag. I've now linked to it as an external file, everything is styled but it's not bringing in the background images. The file structure is the same except the css is in a css folder and the pics are still in a pics folder. Any ideas? Here is what it looks like

```
background:url(pics/alexlogo1.png); 0 0 no-repeat;
```

I've also tried

```
background:url(/pics/alexlogo1.png); 0 0 no-repeat;
```

and

```
background:url(.../pics/alexlogo1.png); 0 0 no-repeat;
```

But I can't seem to get it to work when in a external css file but it works fine when in the head tag.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have the style in a CSS file, then the URL is relative to the CSS file, not the page where it's used.

You should use two periods to get a level down, not three:

```
background:url(../pics/alexlogo1.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
```

(Also, no semicolon after the `url()` when you have more background settings.)

---

Others have suggested to add quotation marks around the URL, but that's not needed for an URL as simple as this. The quotation marks (or apostrophes) are optional according to [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri), and are only needed when the URL contains special characters that would otherwise ruin the CSS syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your path with quotes, like this:

```
background:url("/pics/alexlogo1.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
```

Note this will navigate to the folder `pics`, this folder is in the same directory as the `css` file. This would mean you'd need to do:

```
background:url("../pics/alexlogo1.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
```

In order to leave the `css folder` with `..` and enter the `pics` folder with `/pics`.

**Example:** C:\css\style.css and C:\pics\alexlogo1.png

```
C:\css\style.css
   .. -> C:\
   /pics -> C:\pics` 
   /alexlogo1.png -> C:\pics\alexlogo1.png
```

Comment: @user1910388 You're welcome. Since you're new and may not know this, if there's any answer that correctly answered your question, please accept it by clicking the mark left just below the voting marks. This helps future readers to find the best answer to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
background:url("../pics/alexlogo1.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
```

Only use `..` (two periods) for relative urls.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have a syntax error !!

remove the `;` after `)`

```
background:url(.../pics/alexlogo1.png); 0 0 no-repeat;
```

it should look like this

```
background:url(.../pics/alexlogo1.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
```